# BeanCreationException spring hibernate jsf

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, exception, maven

So I have a huge update. I finally got my sessionFactory to initialize and not be null. I still have (hopefully) the last problem.

I am getting the following stacktrace when I go to store the data in the DAO file.

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:941)
    at com.scott.common.CustomerDAO.saveToDb(CustomerDAO.java:25)
    at com.scott.common.CustomerBackingBean.save(CustomerBackingBean.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 24 more


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="backingBean" class="com.scott.common.CustomerBackingBean"
        scope="request">
        <property name="customer" ref="customerPojo" />
        <property name="customerDao" ref="customerDao" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customerPojo" class="com.scott.common.Customer"></bean>


    <bean id="customerDao" class="com.scott.common.CustomerDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="mysql://localhost:3306/scottdb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.scott.common.Customer</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>




    package com.scott.common;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class CustomerDAO 
{
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /**
     * @return the sessionFactory
     */
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param sessionFactory the sessionFactory to set
     */
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void saveToDb(Customer customer)
    {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(customer);
    }


}
```

Comment: On seeing the exception trace, I think some hibernate dependency is missing. _Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider._ Hence the corresponding class cannot be instantiated and it results in bean creation exception

Comment: Can you post the other config files too?Without looking at actual configuration it's hard to tell where the issue is.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I updated my post to include my pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your current pom file is only using the `hibernate-core` dependency, it seems that the cache extension is not being added.

Try adding the hibernate-ehcache dependency to your pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, I put this dependency in, but still had the same problem. I saw in the stack trace where it was complaining about noclassdeffound cache stuff so I googled that and they told me to change mySessionFactory bean class to class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">. I did that, then had an error that said I did not have an id for my @Entity. I took that out (since I don't know what it did, I was just following tutorials before that had it declared). The server finally ran, but now I have a null pointer exception. I debugged...my sessionfactory variable is not set